# Limiting access to category pages in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories, restrictions

I've recently installed Jason Tadlock's Members plugin which allows restriction of pages and posts but I have built a site using category pages for the majority of the pages. Could anyone tell me how to apply these restrictions to categories or to display the category template as a "page". Ideally, I'd like the links not to show up in the navigation either so that those who don't have access won't know what they are missing.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick peek at the plugin, and it looks like although its intention was not specifically for categorical pages, you can still use its shortcode features within your category.php template to build the content how you want.

Without seeing your code, it's a little hard to give you exactly the answer you need, but this should get you started in the right direction:

```
<?php
$navigation = 'your_navigation_html';
$content = '[access role="editor"]'.$navigation.'[/access]';
echo do_shortcode($content);
?>
```

This example will hide your navigation from everyone but Editors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm having trouble defining the navigation variable for instance if I want to restrict a category called recrutement I would put: `<?php
$navigation = '/category/recrutement';
$content = '[access role="editor"]'.$navigation.'[/access]';
echo do_shortcode($content);
?>
`